# Graph theory notational issue? What does $|N(X)|$ mean?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a bipartite graph $G$ with two parts $X,Y$ if the set $N(X)$ denotes the set of neighbours of $X$ then what does $|N(X)|$ mean? Would it be the total number of vertices in $Y$ that are incident with at least one vertex in $X$? Or is it something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly that. $N(X)$ is the set of neighbours, the vertices adjacent to at least one vertex in $X$. On the other hand $"| |"$ denotes cardinality, or number of elements.

So $|N(X)|$ is exactly what you thought, the number of vertices in the graph that are adjacent to at at least one vertex in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

That is by definition the size of the neighborhood of $X$. That is, it is the total number of vertices in $Y$, such that they are connected by an edge to some vertex in $X$. Of course, we only count each vertex once, regardless of connectivity so long as it is in the neighborhood of $X$.